# How to deploy new code when GCE is working on a job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I started a GCE VM with a Docker image that runs a pub/sub subscriber, which handles the messages and start some big computational work (long running).

When we are ready to deploy new code, how do we ensure all the current running jobs are finished (make the deploy block on task finish). What's the best practice here?

Comment: Depending upon how exactly you are scheduling the [jobs](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Jobs-Page_57344842), you could always check the current status of the job. For example, if you schedule the jobs using [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) you have an option to [describe](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs) it which should provide you the current status of a job.

Comment: How long is your long running job? Do you acknowledge the PubSub message or do you wait the end of the long running job to do this??

Comment: pubsub message is acknowledged before the long running job. Let's say the job can take up to 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can look at Google [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions). Saying this, you can  create a programming function that will respond to some specific events without the need to manage a server or runtime environment.

In particular, it is feasible subscribing specific Cloud function to [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) topic and every message published to this topic will trigger some custom code execution with message contents passed as input data generating `google.pubsub.topic.publish` [event](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#event_structure) type.

Supposedly, you can compose some function, that would be subscribed to the same Pub/Sub topic as the message consumer from your example, triggering the desired deployment upon some condition match, checking the status of the long running job.